# Ошибка AAPT: error: attribute picker_curved not found

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

Я хочу в своём приложении использовать стороннюю библиотеку [WheelPicker](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker).

Вот лэйаут `activity_new_alarm.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:aigestudio="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.aigestudio.wheelpicker.WheelPicker
        android:id="@+id/hourWheel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        aigestudio:picker_curved="true"
        aigestudio:picker_curvedMaxAngle="45"
        aigestudio:picker_cyclic="false"
        aigestudio:picker_dayCount="31"
        aigestudio:picker_itemSpacing="6dp"
        aigestudio:picker_mustBeOnFuture="true"
        aigestudio:picker_selectorColor="@android:color/transparent"
        aigestudio:picker_stepSizeHours="2"
        aigestudio:picker_stepSizeMinutes="5"
        aigestudio:picker_visibleItemCount="7"
        aigestudio:wheel_cyclic="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newAlarmToolbar"
        aigestudio:wheel_visible_item_count="5" />

    ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

При сборке ругается на свойство `picker_curved` элемента WheelPicker ("оно не найдено"):

> ERROR: activity_new_alarm.xml:56: AAPT: error: attribute `picker_curved` (aka thematedev.clock:picker_curved) not found.

Invalidate Caches > Restart не помог. Также пробовал понижать compileSdk до 28, но тут две проблемы: несовместимость более низких уровней с плей маркетом и библиотекой appcompat.

В `build.gradle` подключаю библиотеку так:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation files('D:/Из загрузок/WheelPicker-1.1.3.aar')
}
```

Comment: покажите как добавляли в проект зависимость,  и проектный файл build.gradle

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки, информация `AAPT: error: attribute ____ not found` не выглядит достаточной, чтобы понять причину ошибки.

Comment: ```ERROR: D:\MyApps\MateClock\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_new_alarm.xml:56: AAPT: error: attribute picker_curved (aka thematedev.clock:picker_curved) not found.```

Comment: Действительно, такого атрибута `picker_curved` у WheelPicker нет, но есть, например, [`wheel_curved`](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker/blob/master/WheelPicker/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml). Похоже, вы ошиблись в написании имен атрибутов.

Comment: Нет, в вики он назывался так. К тому же, если я его уберу, начинает ругаться на следующий атрибут, если его тоже уберу - на следующий, и т.д.

Comment: А, да, похоже что в вики была ошибка. Сейчас попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У виджета [`WheelPicker`](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker/blob/master/WheelPicker/src/main/java/com/aigestudio/wheelpicker/WheelPicker.java) не существует атрибута `picker_curved`, но есть атрибут [`wheel_curved`](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker/blob/master/WheelPicker/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml). Возможно, вы хотели использовать именно его.

Список всех доступных атрибутов можно посмотреть [на wiki-странице проекта](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker/wiki/WIKI#xml-attributes-overview).